# Connection reset by peer: socket write error-Java AXIS2 Web-Service

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-axis

I deployed a java axis2 based web-service using tomcat on a machine. the web-service is trying to access a database (foxpro data .dbf) on the same machine,during that test no error occurred .I hosted the database on another machine,the web-service did everything but an error occurred on the return statement (the error did not occur when the web-service and the database were on the same machine)

code:

```
   File file = new File(pcComparisionDirectory+"\\temp");
        file.delete();
        System.out.println("file deleted");
        fileOut.flush();
        System.out.println("file flushed");
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.println("file closed");
        AppendtoLogFile("Comparison sheet generated successfully for REQ: "+tcRFQNO);
        System.out.println("log file");
        connection.close();
        System.out.println("connection closed");
        return "CS_"+tcRFQNO.toUpperCase()+".xlsm";
```

console:

```
    file deleted
    file flushed
    file closed
    log file
    connection closed
    [ERROR] 
     org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:78)
at     org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.sendUsingOutputStream(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:364)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:241)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.sendFault(AxisEngine.java:526)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.handleFault(AxisServlet.java:433)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.processAxisFault(AxisServlet.java:398)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:188)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


    Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1692)
at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.close(BaseStreamWriter.java:288)
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper.close(XMLStreamWriterWrapper.java:46)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.close(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:222)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:192)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
... 24 more


    Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket  write error
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:364)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:326)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:101)
at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:99)
at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.close(BufferingXmlWriter.java:194)
at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1690)
... 29 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at            org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flush(InternalOutputBuffer.java:119)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:793)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:359)
... 35 more
```